# Change system Language Globally

Tags: c#, window

I  want to change System language from my installed system language globally.
When ever i change the language it effect on each and every application of system i.e. default input language.

Can anyone help me regarding this...

I want to implement this feature using window application using C#.

Comment: Have you done any research? Tried anything? What didn't work?

Comment: I have research but fails to get any related example.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Change language of windows OS? Change culture of a single app? What OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I install some third party control like indic tool and it is working fine.